# Use CacheBuilder's cache as a Map

Tags: java, guava

I am currently using a `ConcurrentHashMap` in my application but I need to add the ability to expire entries after a timeout period efficiently (expireAfterWrite) and notify a removal listener whenever an entry is removed.

I see that `CacheBuilder` can provide what I need but I am hesitant to use it because my need is for a map, not a cache. I say this (difference between map and cache) because the guava cache documenatation says this

> Generally, the Guava caching utilities are applicable whenever:
>
> - You are willing to spend some memory to improve speed.
> - You expect that keys will sometimes get queried more than once.
> - Your application would, in principle, work if every value was evicted from the cache immediately -- but you're trying to reduce
>     duplicated work.

Specifically the thrid bullet point is not okay in my application. I am storing values in the map/cache that I want to retrieve later (until its expiration). Also my keys generally get queried only one or two times, not many times to see caching benefits. So you see my requirement is for a map, not a cache in a sense. Is it still a good idea to use CacheBuilder as a map to store values that will expireAfterWrite and provide removalListener capability? Anybody know enough about the internals of CacheBuilder implementation to offer advice?

Comment: I just deleted the offending line from the wiki article; I wrote it originally.  Yes, this is a valid application of `CacheBuilder`.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Of course `MapMaker` caching features are deprecated in favor of [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), my bad. Don't hesitate to use it:

```
Cache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .concurrencyLevel(4) // read docs for more details
    .expireAfterWrite(yourExpireTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build();
```

and then use [`Cache#asMap()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#asMap%28%29) if you want it's view as ConcurrentMap.

<s>Use another utility from Guava - [MapMaker](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html). From docs:</s>

> A builder of ConcurrentMap instances having any combination of the
>   following features:
>
> - keys or values automatically wrapped in weak or soft references
> - least-recently-used eviction when a maximum size is exceeded
> - **time-based expiration of entries**, measured since last access or **last write**
> - notification of evicted (or otherwise removed) entries
> - on-demand computation of values for keys not already present
>
> (...)
>
> The returned map is implemented as a hash table with similar
>   performance characteristics to ConcurrentHashMap. It supports all
>   optional operations of the ConcurrentMap interface. It does not permit
>   null keys or values.

Comment: ...Eh?  `CacheBuilder` is definitely recommended for this use.

Comment: @LouisWasserman +1. I didn't see `@Deprecated` note in MapMaker methods (expiration)... and it's documentation (at class level) is misleading, doesn't mention `Cache` at all and uses old method names. Should I fill an issue?